# classpath in javah

Tags: javah

I'm realy in desperation. I looked up all answeres regarding javah but could not get a solution. I tried:

javah -jni com.aegisguitest.testrobot.recognition.SpyDotNET

The environment variable CLASSPATH is set to the right directory: C:\users\Marcus Tik\workspace\AegisGUITest\bin

I get the error:
Exception in thread "main". java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class name.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: A shot in the dark... Have you tried navigating to the root directory for your code and running it from there?

Comment: If I do so I get the error that javah was not found.

Comment: OK. Enter the complete path to javah.exe and try again. Else, you could just add JDK/bin directory to your PATH system variable

Comment: Thanks! It was the PATH variable. (See my answer)

Comment: Could you explain this any further? I am stuck on the same problem but am at my 50 questions/30 day limit :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to set the PATH environment variable not the CLASSPATH for javah.